# Redirect all except one location on the same domain - too many redirects

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a domain and subdomain.

example.com & beta.example.com

example.com is already working, but I want to redirect all to beta.example.com except example.com/test.

```
location /test {
   return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

location / {
   return 301 https://beta.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Currently with this, when I got to https://example.com/test I'm getting "Too many redirects" page, which is obvious.

What else I can do?

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but it's the same. It should open main domain instead of beta.

Comment: `return 301 https://example.com/test;`